# Kiosk with USB Read/Write support

Tags: server, usb, google-chrome, chromium, kiosk

I am very new to Linux so please bear with me!

Our company have recently implemented a complete USB lock-down policy on all Windows machines. As a workaround, we have installed OwnCloud on one of our servers and provided staff with 'Kiosk' machines which are off the domain and connected to the 'Guest' Wi-Fi only. This however gives us no management on these machines as they are off the domain. If a machine was to get a virus or malware, we would not be alerted!

I then looked at Ubuntu for security purposes mainly and the different 'Kiosk' flavours there are out there including Porteus Kiosk, Ubuntu Desktop (stripped) and Instant Web Kiosk. They do not give us exactly what we need which is a simple Chromium browser that can access and save files to a USB by default and upload files from USB respectively. That's it! The Kiosk flavours above do not give us read / write access to USB unfortunately.

The other idea I had, because we do not have any Linux experts working here in IT, was is there a way we could build up a Linux server that would push out stand policy settings and 'builds' to a machine for us. If someone changes any of the settings on a Ubuntu Kiosk, we would simply rebuild it remotely by pushing out the settings again.

Any ideas please? Your help and ideas would be much appreciated indeed.

Thank you

Danny